# How do you work this out to find the eigenvalues (λ)?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$λ^3$-7$λ^2$=0

I know the eigenvalues are $λ_1$=0 and $λ_2$=7 but I'm not sure how to get there.

Comment: Can you find the roots of that polynomial? Do you know why they are the eigenvalues?

Comment: Factor out $\lambda^2$ on the LHS. Then remember: "A product is zero if at least one factor is zero."

Comment: Please provide more context. I suppose you're trying to find the eigenvalues of a matrix: what matrix is it?

Comment: @user380468 You´re welcome.